# KairosDB: is it a good idea to create many metrics?

Tags: cassandra, time-series, kairosdb

I plan to use KairosDB to store monitoring data for my VMs' disk IO. Now I am thinking that I should create a metric for every VM, which will lead to many metrics in the DB, or just create a metric for all VMs and use tags to identify data for each VM.

I am not sure if a large number of metrics will kill the performance or hurt query.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use tags. Having single metric for the same data provides you the benefit to execute aggregation queries for all VMs collecting this metric, e.g. total disk I/O write bytes for all VMs.

Comment: @SergeiRodionov Good point! Thanks

Comment: Same comment as Sergei. You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same comment as Sergei. 
To answer your other question having many metrics will not impact the performances.

But having metrics with very high tag cardinality must be avoided, but in your case you should not have to (by high cardinality I mean non discrete values, or thousands of values).

Comment: This was really helpful @Loic. Thank you!